# Module 'self' has no attribute 'file' error in class format

Tags: python, pandas, self

I am building a python code to validate the email address and the phone number in a given CSV file using pandas and I want to write a separate CSV file with only the validated values. I am totally new to python and I have written a code for the functionality as follows:

```
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
import pandas as pd
import re

file = r'sample.csv'
filtered = r'filtered.csv'
valid = r'Valid.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(file)

def eVali(dataFrame):
    try:
        validate_email(dataFrame)                 
        return True
    except EmailNotValidError:
        return False


def phoneValid(dataFrame):
    if re.search("\w{3}-\w{3}-\w{4}",dataFrame):
        return True
    else:
        return False

df["Email_validate"] = df['email'].apply(eVali)

df_fltrd = df[df['Email_validate']]
#del df_fltrd['Email_validate']
print(df_fltrd)

df_fltrd["Phone_validate"] =df_fltrd['phone'].apply(phoneValid)

df_valid = df_fltrd[df_fltrd["Phone_validate"]]
del df_valid["Phone_validate", "Email_validate"]
print(df_valid)

df_fltrd.to_csv(filtered)
df_valid.to_csv(valid)
```

This code is working fine and I could create a new CSV with validated values as I require. but when I tried to organize this code as a proper class with the proper method it gives an error saying,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\myTasks\validator.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Validator:
  File "E:\myTasks\validator.py", line 47, in Validator
    validation(self.file)
AttributeError: module 'self' has no attribute 'file'
```

This is the class I created.

**Validator.py**

```
    import self as self
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
import pandas as pd
import re


class Validator:

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = r'sample.csv'
        self.outFile =r'filteredSample.csv'



    def emailValid(dataframe):
        try:
            validate_email(dataframe)
            return True
        except EmailNotValidError:
            return False

    def phoneValid(dataframe):
        if re.search("\w{3}-\w{3}-\w{4}", dataframe):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def validation(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(self.file)
        df = df.copy();
        df["Email_validate"] = df['email'].apply(Validator.emailValid)

        df_filtered = df[df['Email_validate']]
        print(df_filtered)

        df_filtered["Phone_validate"] = df_filtered['phone'].apply(Validator.phoneValid)

        df_valid = df_filtered[df_filtered["Phone_validate"]]
        del df_valid["Email_validate"]
        del df_valid["Phone_validate"]
        print(df_valid)

        df_valid.to_csv(self.outFile)

    validation(self)
```

Can someone please help me with this. It will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't call an instance method from the class itself

```
validation(self)
```

This bit should be outside of your class, for example it could be called from your main function after having instantiated your Validator object.

```
my_validator = Validator()
my_validator.validation()
```

Comment: have a look at here:
https://repl.it/repls/FirmLooseParameter
Please validate my answer if it works

Comment: Thankyou @Raphael St for the quick response! It worked this way!!! Thank you so much. Upvoted and accepted as the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not import *self*.
*self* is the instance you are in at the time of code execution.

Your problem is that you did not understand classes yet. You tried to call a class method within the class which python does but toes not like.

I'd suggest you have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html and/or https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp.

You want to push the last line to the end and add

```
def main():
    i = Validator()
    i.validation()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the consideration you gave. I really appreciate it. Upvoted!